# What does a create function do in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This snippet is giving error in a program I have:

```
var validateUserSchema = {email: email, validationKey: validateString};
ValidateUserSchema.create(validateUserSchema, function(err, newlyCreated){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Can you explain what this code is trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

It creates an object in database.

The code you mention does the following:

1. Creates an object `validateUserSchema` with two properties: `email` and `validationKey`.
2. The `create` function on `ValidateUserSchema` model stores the `validateUserSchema` previously declared object. This function accepts a callback that is called after the creation. If there was an error in the transaction, the `error` object will contain info about that error. If the transaction succeeded, `newlyCreated` object represents the new object that has just been stored.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the issue with my code, and I am writing this answer to make sure anyone looking for it later may not waste time finding an issue.

The snippet in question is just creating a doc based on Schema/model created earlier.
The error in my case was that I added an extra '}' before this snippet so it was being treated as unowned variables. Due to which 'email' was left uninitialized.

When in a thread of actions, the 'email' must ideally have a value, which will make this work. And it did.